# How to save locally data from a server database to a local database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

I have an application connecting to a SQL Server database. I want to "download" some of the data to be able to get some information without an internet connection when I start my program a second time.

Do I have to create a local database (SQL Server CE - `.sdf`) to store the data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's one way to do it.

Are we talking about an Occasionally Connected App here? In that case you should also look at the MS Sync framework. To consider syncing data between the local .sdf DB and your server's DB.

Comment: Yes, it's an Occasionally Connected App. I'll check this framework. thanks